# view daterange , end date not correct

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm selecting documents in a view by daterange. The start date is alway correct but the end date isn't. The selection goes from the startdate till the last entry.
My code is :

```
var vDateRange = session.createDateRange(sessionScope.selectedStartDate, sessionScope.selectedEndDate);
var projects:NotesView = database.getView('visits_by_date_VB')
var viewNav:NotesViewNavigator = projects.createViewNav();
var viewEntryCollection:NotesViewEntryCollection = projects.getAllEntriesByKey(vDateRange);
var viewEnt:NotesViewEntry = viewEntryCollection.getFirstEntry();

var output:string = "";
while (viewEnt != null) {
 output += "<tr>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[0]; + "</td>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[3] + "</td>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[4] + "</td>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[5] + "</td>";
 output += "</tr>";
viewEnt = viewNav.getNext(viewEnt);
}
```

**EDIT**

Picking up dates with following code :

```
<xe:djDateTextBox id="StartDate"
                            defaultValue="#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedStartDate}"
                            value="#{sessionScope.selectedStartDate}">
                            <xp:this.converter>
                                <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                                    dateStyle="full">
                                </xp:convertDateTime>
                            </xp:this.converter>
                        </xe:djDateTextBox>
       <xe:djDateTextBox id="EndDate"
                            defaultValue="#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedEndDate}"
                            value="#{sessionScope.selectedEndDate}">
                            <xp:this.converter>
                                <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                                    dateStyle="full">
                                </xp:convertDateTime>
                            </xp:this.converter>
                        </xe:djDateTextBox>
```

First column of the view is a date /time "style" sorted Ascending
The field on the form that stores the dates is a date time field .

Comment: How are your dates stored/formatted in sessionScope.selectedStartDate and sessionScope.selectedEndDate?

Comment: What do you mean the end date isn't correct? can you add a picture of the lookup columns in the view

Comment: I mean the entries (viewEnt) are gooing beyond the end date of the vDateRange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this one line

```
viewEnt = viewNav.getNext(viewEnt);
```

to

```
viewEnt = viewEntryCollection.getNextEntry(viewEnt);
```

and it will work.

You initialize `viewNav` with the complete view content. That's why it starts with the right date from viewEntryCollection but runs always to view's end. You don't need the `viewNav` in this code and can delete this line.